# Why is my html not displaying the user interface but when I dd it can be displayed

Tags: html, laravel

**Show.blade.php**
this is the show that is supposed to display the wanted data

```
@extends('layouts.app') 

@section('content')

  @foreach($dives as $dives)
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $dives->entry_time }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $dives->dive_date }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $dives->location }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $dives->dive_spot }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ $dives->description }}</li>
  </ul>
  @endforeach
@endsection
```

**DiveController for show**
this is the code for show controller

```
    $dives = Dive::all();
    return view('dive.show', compact('dives'));
```

Comment: use different variable names inside foreach loop.  e.g . @foreach($dives as $dive)

Comment: What error do you get? What do you see vs. what you expect?

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: no error, just a blank page

Comment: its okay ive fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Both variables are same in foreach

Try with

```
Foreach( $dives as $dive){

}
```